# Excel Compatibility mode stopping FileSystemWatcher events

Tags: excel-2010, xls, filesystemwatcher

When opening old .xls files in Office 2010 all events regarding changes no longer get caught, filesystemwatcher is still monitoring the file because if i open it from the Temp folder an event will be fired but it's connection to Excel when it is initially opened seems to be lost.

Has anyone seen this before? Searching through google i've not turned up much.

Thanks